Visual Studio's Go To Definition is pulling up metadata ONLY after update
Ever since I updated up to 17.11.3 in Visual Studio 2022, when ever I CTRL+CLICK (or right click and click Go To Definition) on some classes, some methods, some functions that belong to a VB.Net project from an ASPX file in our website project, it opens a metadata window (A window only containing a very skimmed down version of the actual file).
Even more strange, I restart Visual Studio, and within the first 30 seconds of Visual Studio being open, it will go to the correct file and show me all of the code. After that 30 seconds, the issue happens again.
I've looked at some similar posts, which are years old, but none of these issues apply, because like I said it works for the first 30 seconds.
when ever I CTRL+CLICK (or right click and click Go To Definition) on some classes, some methods, some functions that belong to a VB.Net project from an ASPX file in our website project, it opens a metadata window.
Tried deleting a .suo file mentioned in another article. Didn't help.

Take a look at your extensions (Visual Studio, top menu, extensions, manage extensions, installed, tools). Are any of them code assistants?  Maybe try to disable one and restart to see if that helps.

Extensions or background tasks may be initializing after the first 30 seconds and interfering with file navigation.
Try to disable any non-essential extensions, especially those related to project management, refactoring, or language services.
Restart Visual Studio and check if the issue is resolved.
Also check for any background tasks that might be starting after Visual Studio launches. Go to View > Other Windows > Task Status Center and see if any tasks start running after Visual Studio opens (like indexing or background analysis).
Delete visual studio's cache files might help. Navigate to %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio. Delete the ComponentModelCache folder.

Tried all of these, unfortunately, my issue is still not resolved. I have 5 extensions made by Microsoft, no others. No background tasks. Clearing cache didn't help. Thanks for trying to help!

17.11.4 has been released, try to update Visual Studio to see if the problem fixed
